# Django admin GenericForeignKey object_id lookup

Tags: django, django-admin, django-contenttypes

I'm looking for great way of selecting object of selected content_type (component_type). Django serves the raw id field where the user can input an integer. Is there a way to make it look more like [the django grappelli solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkAuq.png) (the small search button)? Like an 3rd part app to install which modifies admin template and adds ONLY this one feature instead of full django admin template? Or there is a good-looking template which has this option (because grappelli looks so bad). Thanks in advance